# ERC20 total supply distribution

Tags: solidity, erc-20

For an ERC20 token, what is a typical total supply distribution?

I'm about a month into solidity, coming from a .net full stack background. I have got a contract developed including adding liquidity in the contract. Before deploying to test net, I want to understand how more about the total supply and typical minting functionality. In my situation the mint is only called from the constructor on contract creation, creating the total supply. From analysing different tokens and the deployers wallet transactions. Common practice seems to mint the token to msg.sender (the deployer) then send tokens back to the contract inorder to create a liquidity pool. Is there a standard total supply distribution ? surely it's a bad idea to put 100% of the coins in the liquidity but I'm guessing that effects the market cap. Just looking for advice on this.

Comment: Don't think there's any standard value for that, it totally depends on your use cases of the token. But yeah, I'll follow this question in case someone comes up with any explanation.

Comment: Yeah I'm starting to think there isn't really a standard value, the openzeppelin documentation suggest its just customizable to each use case. I'm trying to understand how this now affects the price and market cap, do you know of any good resources around those topics ?